# Parse XML Elements with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:lang="el-gr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title type="text">name.gr</title>
<updated>2011-07-23</updated>
<link href="link" />
<entry>    
  <title type="html">Οι επιθέσεις σε σκανδιναβικές χώρες</title>
  <summary type="text">Η Νορβηγία, μία από τις σκανδιναβικές χώρες, έζησε μετά από πάρα  πολλά χρόνια (2006) τον τρόμο. Δείτε αναλυτικά τις τελευταίες «τυφλές» επιθέσεις τα τελευταία χρόνια:...</summary>
  <published>2011-07-23T12:54:00+03:00</published>    
  <link href="link" />
</entry>
```

i want to parse some of the elements inside . For that i use the following LINQ code.

```
var list = from y in xelement.Descendants("entry")
           select new Update()
           {
               Title = y.Element("title").Value,
               Pubdate = y.Element("published").Value,
               Descr = y.Element("content").Value,
               Link = y.Element("link").Attribute("href").Value
           };
```

But it does not work. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to retrive an element named *content* which doesn't exist in your XML, shouldn't this be *summary*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodes are all in the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace. Therefore you need to prefix the queries with this namespace, otherwise the query tries to find those elements in the empty namespace.

```
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var list = from y in xelement.Descendants(atom+"entry")
               select new Update()
               {
                   Title = y.Element(atom+"title").Value,
                   Pubdate = y.Element(atom+"published").Value,
                   Descr = y.Element(atom+"content").Value,
                   Link = y.Element(atom+"link").Attribute("href").Value
               };
```

Comment: isn't that only applicable if each XML element is marked with the appropriate NS prefix? e.g. `<atom:title... />`.

Comment: No. The root XML element (`feed`) redefines the empty/default namespace prefix with the `xmlns` attribute. Therefore, all elements starting with the one on which the `xmlns` is defined are in that namespace (unless redefined).

Answer (score 0):

In your XML example, there is missing "feed" endtag and you are using an element "content", but I guess "summary" is correct.