# LINQ to XML Select Statement - No Results

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse XML Elements with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799753/parse-xml-elements-with-linq)

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TestDataset xmlns="http://tempuri.org/TestDataset.xsd">
  <TaxRate>
    <Code>GST</Code>
    <Rate>0.05</Rate>
    <LastModified>2010-03-31T17:03:24.063-04:00</LastModified>
    <Deleted>0</Deleted>
    <AbbreviationEN>GST</AbbreviationEN>
    <AbbreviationFR>GST</AbbreviationFR>
    <GLSubCode>GST</GLSubCode>
  </TaxRate>
  <TaxRate>
    <Code>PST</Code>
    <Rate>0.08</Rate>
    <LastModified>2010-03-31T17:03:24.063-04:00</LastModified>
    <Deleted>0</Deleted>
    <AbbreviationEN>PST</AbbreviationEN>
    <AbbreviationFR>PST</AbbreviationFR>
    <GLSubCode>PST</GLSubCode>
  </TaxRate>
</TestDataset>
```

And I am trying to select it's contents with the following query:

```
XDocument data = LoadTestData("TaxRate.xml");
var taxdata = (from x in data.Elements("TaxRate")
              select new
              {
                  Code = x.Element("Code").Value,
                  Rate = x.Element("Rate").Value,
                  AbbreviationEN = x.Element("AbbreviationEN").Value,
                  AbbreviationFR = x.Element("AbbreviationFR").Value,
                  GLSubCode = x.Element("GLSubCode").Value
               }).ToList();
```

However I keep getting no results, LoadTestData is loading the XML document fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to include the namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/TestDataset.xsd";
XDocument data = LoadTestData("TaxRate.xml");
var taxdata = (from x in data.Descendants(ns + "TaxRate")
              select new
              {
                  Code = x.Element(ns + "Code").Value,
                  Rate = x.Element(ns + "Rate").Value,
                  AbbreviationEN = x.Element(ns + "AbbreviationEN").Value,
                  AbbreviationFR = x.Element(ns + "AbbreviationFR").Value,
                  GLSubCode = x.Element(ns + "GLSubCode").Value
               }).ToList();
```

Although the namespace in your XML file is the default namespace, you still need to include it in your query.

Answer (score 3):

You have to respect the namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/TestDataset.xsd";
var taxdata = (from x in data.Elements(ns+"TaxRate")
          select new
          {
              Code = x.Element(ns+"Code").Value,
              Rate = x.Element(ns+"Rate").Value,
              AbbreviationEN = x.Element(ns+"AbbreviationEN").Value,
              AbbreviationFR = x.Element(ns+"AbbreviationFR").Value,
              GLSubCode = x.Element(ns+"GLSubCode").Value
           }).ToList();
```